# java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

Please understand that the question may be a little dizzy because it's my first time asking a question. Also, please understand that grammar may be strange because I am not good at English and use a translator.

I'm a person who is making apps using java in Android studios.

There was a continuous error trying to use Bluetooth. There were so many errors that I could easily find a solution, but it didn't apply to me.

**Error Log**

```
Process: org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2, PID: 10852
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2/org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10158, packageName = org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@f43a396, next = null }: AdapterService getBondedDevices
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10158, packageName = org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@f43a396, next = null }: AdapterService getBondedDevices
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.getBondedDevices(IBluetooth.java:3077)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices(BluetoothAdapter.java:2491)
        at org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2.MainActivity.showPairedDevicesListDialog(MainActivity.java:300)
        at org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:80)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

I think this sentence in the middle is the cause of the error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10158, packageName = org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@f43a396, next = null }: AdapterService getBondedDevices
```

But I've already applied a solution to the problem. This is my Manifest.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.techtown.push.bluetoothtest2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Bluetoothtest2">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I applied it because I saw that I needed "android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission." However, errors continue to occur.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or did I make a mistake in mainactivty.java?

For your information, I made it like this when I made a project.

> minimun sdk : API 16 : Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean)

If there is no problem with the file you wrote down, please tell me to review the Java code again.
Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

since Android 6.0 not every permission is granted just because its placed in manifest. you have to handle [runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime) flow with `BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` one (how to request in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting))

> The BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions are runtime permissions. Therefore, you must explicitly request user approval in your app before you can look for Bluetooth devices, make a device discoverable to other devices, or communicate with already-paired Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Sometimes you can get away with it when debugging your phone... but when you deploy to the Play Store, it will just crash/quit.

If using flutter, look at https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Comment: @ThorMJ do you know why does this error not arise while debugging?

Answer (score 16):

You should declare BLUETOOTH_SCAN and permissions in the Manifest and in the Activity.java

For example:

1. AndroiManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

2. MainActivity.java

```
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
    };
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
    };
```

and

```
    private void checkPermissions(){
        int permission1 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int permission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
        if (permission1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    1
            );
        } else if (permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,
                    1
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be good if you add the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to your answer.

Comment: where do you call checkPermissions() ?

Comment: @Phil In my case, ```checkPermissions(...)```call was in the ```onCreate(...)``` method in the MainActivity.java file

Comment: @rojarand works for me with compile/target SDK 31 (Android 12).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to request permission for `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

step-1: Declare BLUETOOTH_SCAN in AndroidManifest.xml

Step-2: Declare in Activity.XML

Step-3: Check for permission(BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)

For reference https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions